# Designing template for Ruby on Rails view. What and where to learn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates

I have a project going on, and I am in charge of the front-end design, whereas my developers will work on the back-end with Ruby on Rails.

I do not know Ruby on Rails, and am designing front-end using XHTML, CSS, jQuery, 960.gs CSS Framework. My developer is supposed to take my design and connect the elements of back-end to it, with Ajax too.

What are the things that I should know while designing the template/view so that I won't kick my developers' asses with my design? How to help the connecting of elements painless? I understand I must avoid . Some Ruby on Rails developers also prefer Blueprint CSS Framework over 960.gs.

Any guidance? Thanks.

Comment: Protip: When using multiple words for a tag you should separate them with hyphens, as I did. Otherwise they show up as separate tags. There's not a lot of point in tagging your question "on", so make sure you use hyphens in the future. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the Rails templating system is quite flexible and will enable developers to create even complex designs. The CSS framework should not make such a difference. However if they are using Rails 2.x it is markedly easier to use Prototype instead of jQuery. However Rails 3.x is also agnostic to javascript library.

A relatively good overview is the [official guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html). You might also try out [this tool for cutting up your views and layouts](http://markupslicer.com/).

Comment: Thanks. But let's just say that I have zero knowledge in Ruby on Rails. What's the guide?

Answer (score 1):

I can speak from the developer point of view.

The things that piss me off are too complicated css structures, keep it simple and abstract as you can.

The other things is naming classes and ids, in general try to find out what models the developer is using and name your classes and ids accordingly. E.g. for a blog with posts:
`#posts .post` for a post in the index view  and `#post` for a post in the show view.
I never care what css framework the designer uses, as long as it works.
And lastely, if you design different html pages, be aware that we often have only one or two layouts, that's eg. `/views/layouts/application.html.erb` and we usually try to keep that number low as possible.

jQuery is find, ever been my preferred choice over rails' own prototype.

Comment: Well, I don't know what are the IDs and Classes they are using. But I will sit with them together to incorporate the front-end to their back-end.

Comment: with ids and classes I meant the html id and classes. If you are uncertain, ask your developer for a simple naming convention. Ruby on Rails is full of those naming conventions, causing a steep learning curve but once you got the idea it's always the same :)